# Date conversions in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a sqlite DB and the column dateID is stored as an integer e.g. 20131101 being Nov 1, 2013. I need to calculate # of days from the start of a period - say beginning of a period into a dayNumber column.

Here is my sql:

```
update temptable set dayNumber = dateid - (select min(dateid) -1 from temptable)
```

It was doing fine until I cross months e.g. 20131101 - (say) 20131017 and I get 85 instead of the 15 I had hoped for - Can anyone help me with the date conversions so I can get 15?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had your dates stored in one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime), you could use the [built-in date functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) to do calculations on these values.

To convert from `yyyymmdd` to `yyyy-mm-dd`, use an expression like this:

```
substr(dateid, 1, 4) || '-' || substr(dateid, 5, 2) || '-' || substr(dateid, 7, 2)
```

To convert a date into a number of days, use, for example, `julianday`:

```
UPDATE temptable
SET dayNumber = julianday(substr(dateid, 1, 4) || '-' ||
                          substr(dateid, 5, 2) || '-' ||
                          substr(dateid, 7, 2)) -
                (SELECT julianday(MIN(substr(dateid, 1, 4) || '-' ||
                                      substr(dateid, 5, 2) || '-' ||
                                      substr(dateid, 7, 2))) - 1
                 FROM temptable)
```